# PHP Mailer - "Could not connect to SMTP host"

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp

Estou tentando enviar um email utilizando PhpMailer, porém, sem sucesso.

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'meuemail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'minhasenha123';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('meuemail@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('meuemail@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

A mensagem de erro que recebo é a seguinte:

> ```
> 2018-02-18 16:22:22 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP k2sm16846924qtk.60 - gsmtp<br> 2018-02-18 16:22:22 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO localhost<br> 2018-02-18 16:22:23 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2804:431:b705:30c:3c68:a6f0:fd8e:b468]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8<br> 2018-02-18 16:22:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS<br> 2018-02-18 16:22:23 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<br> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.<br> 2018-02-18 16:22:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br> 2018-02-18 16:22:23 <br> 2018-02-18 16:22:23 <br> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.<br> Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
> ```

Obs: Fiz várias alterações, inclusive algumas sugeridas em certos tópicos por aqui, porém, sem sucesso. Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Obs 2: Já ativei a permissão para aplicações menos confiáveis no gmail.

**edit: Existem vários tópicos falando sobre o problema, porém, nenhum destes funcionou para meu caso. Adicionei a solução às respostas.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a solução adicionando o seguinte trecho:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
 )
);
```

Comment: Isto apenas desliga a segurança, o que realmente é algo que pode ser um problema... o seu problema ou é com a extensão de SSL que esta inativa, ou com a versão do seu PHP ou com a versão do phpmailer que você esta usando (a maior parte dos problemas é que as pessoas baixam o phpmailer de links não oficiais e por isto acabam por usar versões obsoletas)

Comment: Eu baixei o PhpMailer via Composer, comando retirado do Github, então creio que esta seja a versão mais atual. Mas obrigado por estas informações amigo, creio que serão úteis.

Comment: O erro ocorre somente no seu localhost ou ocorre no seu site também? Ocorre em ambos?
 Mande as informações do seu ambiente que esta falhando, pra isto use o [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.phpinfo.php)

Comment: Por enquanto estou trabalhando no site rodando ele localhost via WAMP Guilherme, ainda não testei colocar no ar.

Comment: Então posta o conteudo do phpinfo, pode ser a versão do PHP ou o openssl que esta inativo.

Comment: Não consigo enviar por aqui, é um texto muito extenso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73347/discussion-between-dev-john-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Answer (score 2):

Troque a porta para **465**.
Ex:

```
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Comment: Porém é necessário ter `SSL` --> https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Obrigado amigo, tentei aqui mas não funcionou. Agora o erro é o seguinte: Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o Google (por questões de segurança) está bloqueando o acesso à conta através da sua aplicação.

Para liberar o acesso, faça o seguinte:

**1.** Logue em sua conta no Gmail

**2.** Acesse https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

**3.** Clique em <kbd>Continuar</kbd>

Aguarde alguns segundos e faça novo teste e seu Phpmailer deve funcionar. Você poderá enviar tanto por `ssl` (porta 465) quanto por `tls` (porta 587).

### Edit

Após discussão nos comentários, foi verificado que a solução acima se aplica a problemas de autorização e não de conexão com o smtp do Gmail. No entanto a solução acima ficará publicada caso alguém tenha problema semelhante, pois pode haver certa confusão entre uma coisa e outra.

O problema da pergunta foi resolvido a partir **[desta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36405556/1377664)** e respondido pelo AP **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277141/8063)**.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo. Tentei isto, porém e o erro persiste.

Comment: Eu testei em servidor Windows e funcionou beleza. Vc tá usando Linux? Tem acesso ao php.ini?

Comment: Eu estou usando servidor Windows (WAMP). Sim, tenho acesso ao php.ini

Comment: Sim, está normal.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, neste link que você mandou encontrei a solução!!!!

Comment: Diz qual foi para que eu possa adicionar na resposta.

Comment: Acabei de adicionar.

Comment: Deixe ela, pode ser útil para alguém.

Comment: Blz, vou deixar então. Abs!